# How to add leading zeros to ip address using python

Tags: python, string

How can i add zeros to the leading part in each byte of ip address using python so that each byte will always be in 3 digit format.
The input and output should be like

```
1.2.3.4     ==>> 001.002.003.004
1.192.122.5 ==>> 001.192.122.005
192.168.1.1 ==>> 192.168.001.001
```

Comment: What is your input variable? That is, how is a single ip address stored in your code?

Comment: Have you look at Python string formatting? https://pyformat.info/ may be a good reference (which has links to the official documentation).

Comment: it is stored as a string like ip="1.2.3.4"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
ip = '1.2.3.4'
'.'.join(i.zfill(3) for i in ip.split('.'))

'001.002.003.004'
```

Comment: Nice, with the use of `zfill`. Note that you don't need the square brackets: `join` works on a generator expression.

Comment: @00 good point. I changed that

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
ip = '1.2.3.4'
print('.'.join([(3 - len(i)) * '0' + i for i in ip.split('.')]))
```

Output:

```
001.002.003.004
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zfill()`:

```py
def addZeros(ip, zero_num = 3):
    parts = ip.split('.')
    parts = [part.zfill(zero_num) for part in parts]
    return '.'.join(parts)
    
print(addZeros('1.2.3.4'))
# 001.002.003.004
```

Comment: If you make it a function `addZeros`, perhaps it's nicer to specify how many zeros are to be added (or rather, the value of `zfill`) as a function argument (with a default value).

Comment: @00 You're right. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
def zero_adder(digit):
    if len(digit) == 3:
        return digit
    return zero_adder("0" + str(digit))

ips = ["1.192.122.5", "192.168.1.1", "1.2.3.4"]
output = []
for ip in ips:
    ips_with_zero = []
    for num in ip.split("."):
        ips_with_zero.append(zero_adder(num))
    output.append(".".join(ips_with_zero))
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an f-string with proper format:

```
ip = '.'.join(f'{int(n):03d}' for n in ip.split('.'))
```